# A Full Screen Web App with Scala? or a GUI Framework for this?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm need to do a app with this requirements:

-Remote Database connection
-Full Screen
-Some widgets must to update in real time

I'm thinking that it can't do with a web framework because I need a Full screen dedicated app maybe I'm wrong...

Somebody knows what GUI framework is best-suited (Well Documented, samples) for Scala?

and

Is there a way to do a full screen app with Play 2/Scala?

Thanks in advance.
Chris.

Edit: The App must be a Kiosk like App (w/touchscreen)

Comment: Why do you need this? do you need to setup for an example a kiosk in public area, or something else, that info is quite important for this question.

Comment: This is definitely possible with Play and browser APIs (as mentioned in the answer below).  The real-time updates can use WebSockets or Comet in Play.

Comment: Excuse me, I wrote unclear... it should be "Why do you need a fullscreen?" of course 'realtime' and `remote DB connection` are basic built-in possibilities of the Play

Comment: Sorry, yeah I need a kiosk - like App, for a university lunchroom, every guy entering their number id on a touch screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Full screen would most definitely be handled client-side. [This answer demonstrates how to make a window full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7525760/1214194). Using that, you most definitely could use Play! (or any other web framework, or no framework at all). If you're most comfortable with web programming, this might be the way to go.

Since you mention a GUI application, I imagine you're not just making a normal web site that you want full screen – that is considered bad design practice. However, for a terminal of some sort, that would work well for you.

If you'd prefer to deploy an application for clients to run, check out [Scala's Swing libraries](http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/sids/imaier/Mon,%202009-11-02,%2008:55/scala-swing-design.pdf). There are plenty of examples online and in Martin Odersky's Programming Scala book.

Comment: Andrew, which is exactly a bad practice? a webapp running at full screen on a kiosk f/e?

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. A normal web site that goes full screen would be bad design. Just imagine if every other blog you went to tried to go full screen.

For a kiosk, it's a great option. It really boils down to what you're more comfortable with on how you build it.

Also, most browsers have a native full screen function. On many PCs, it's F11.