# Getting fullscreen mode to my browser using jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I enter full screen mode using just Javascript/JQuery code? The goal is to enter fullscreen mode like when you press F11 in the browser, but then programmatically.

Comment: you can see it here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen

Answer (score 48):

You can activate full screen mode using vanilla JavaScript without jQuery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Full Screen Test</title>
</head>

<body id="body">
    <h1>test</h1>

    <script>
    var elem = document.getElementById("body");

    elem.onclick = function() {
        req = elem.requestFullScreen || elem.webkitRequestFullScreen || elem.mozRequestFullScreen;
        req.call(elem);
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

One thing that is important to note, you can only request full screen mode  when a user performs an action (e.g. a click). You can't request full screen mode without a user action<sup>[[1]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode#When_a_fullscreen_request_fails)</sup> (e.g. on page load).

Here is a cross browser function to toggle full screen mode ([as obtained from the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode#Toggling_fullscreen_mode)):

```
function toggleFullScreen() {
  if (!document.fullscreenElement &&    // alternative standard method
      !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement ) {  // current working methods
    if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
      document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
      document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    }
  } else {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
      document.msExitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
      document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    }
  }
}
```

For more information, check out the [MDN page on full screen APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode).

Comment: Is there any reason to not use short statement like `req = elem.requestFullScreen || elem.webkitRequestFullScreen || elem.mozRequestFullScreen;` to get supported function, but use `else if` instead?

Comment: @MaxYari At least Chrome will throw an "Illegal invocation" exception when storing `document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen` in a variable `x` and then using `x()` or `x.call()`.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a working demo for making the browser full screen

http://johndyer.name/lab/fullscreenapi/

Comment: @deepthi: which version of mozilla browser you are using? For `Mozilla 16.0.2` version is working fine...

Comment: I am using mozilla 16.0.2 only

Answer (score 2):

You can use freely available jquery plugins for this purpose, check these-
[jquery full screen](http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/08/5-free-jquery-fullscreen-plugins.html),
[Jquery full screen](http://www.ailis.de/~k/archives/66-jQuery-Fullscreen-Plugin.html),[jquery full screen](http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/)

Comment: I tried these.. but it is working for mozilla, but the screen is looking different compare to the actual screen

Comment: what is the difference you are finding, attach screen shot

Answer (score 2):

If you need a plugin that supports versions of IE prior to IE11 (IE8-10), take a look at [jQuery.fullscreen](https://github.com/private-face/jquery.fullscreen). IE did not support this feature natively until [IE11](http://caniuse.com/#search=fullscreen).

Answer (score 2):

If you need JQuery to get ease of element selection, then you can do this:

```
var viewer = $("#parentid .classname .childelement")[0];
var rFS = viewer.mozRequestFullScreen || viewer.webkitRequestFullscreen || viewer.requestFullscreen;
    rFS.call(viewer);
```

Comment: Works for modern browsers and without a plugin which deserves an up-vote.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code

```
var el = document.documentElement,
  rfs = el.requestFullscreen
    || el.webkitRequestFullScreen
    || el.mozRequestFullScreen
    || el.msRequestFullscreen 
;

rfs.call(el);
```

Comment: Is there anything new in your answer or did you just copy stuff from the other answers?

Comment: the significant part is `document.documentElement` for requesting and only `document` for exiting

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but maybe somebody could need this. I was looking for a solution for getting fullsreen mode for browser by jQuery and i've found this solution. I highly recommend Sindre Sorhus's screenfull.js plugin. Here you can get the file.

https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js

There are also how tos and demos available in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try with window.resizeTo(x,y) method.

```
var  w = window.open('','', 'width=100,height=100');

w.resizeTo(w.screen.availHeight, w.screen.availWidth);

 w.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the full screen JQuery which is given into the GitHub. File downloading link [GitHub]:https://github.com/private-face/jquery.fullscreen

2.add the release folder into the footer section and also add Jquery.min.js  file into the page.
3.Give an id #open is an id of button where we apply the click event on it.

```
<!-- On click button, where we change full screen -->
    <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" id="open" data-myval="1" title="FullScreen"> </a>
<!-- Js File add into the footer-->
 <script src="<?= base_url('assets/vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js') ?>"></script>
 <script src="<?= base_url('assets/release/jquery.fullscreen.min.js') ?>"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript"> 
     $(function() {   $('#open').click(function() 
      {
          var value = $('#open').attr('data-myval');
          if(value == 1 )
          {
          var values = $('#open').attr('data-myval',2);
          console.log(values);
             $('body').fullscreen();
             return false;
          }
          else
          {
             var values = $('#open').attr('data-myval',1);
             $.fullscreen.exit();
             return false;
          }       
          });
    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score -2):

In case have a button or anything else, We can use this script :

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function fullScreen() {
    var el = document.documentElement
        , rfs = // for newer Webkit and Firefox
               el.requestFullScreen
            || el.webkitRequestFullScreen
            || el.mozRequestFullScreen
            || el.msRequestFullScreen
    ;
    if (typeof rfs != "undefined" && rfs) {
        rfs.call(el);
    } else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject != "undefined") {
        // for Internet Explorer
        var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        if (wscript != null) {
            wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
        }
    }

}
// End -->
```

With a button. Everything is easy by `<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fullScreen();"><BUTTON></a>`
But How can I load that script on pageload. That's mean that webform will be fullscreen on pageload without any click on anything.