# Automatically Opening Chrome in Full Screen on Mac OS X

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Recently I stumbled upon a new brand of pop ups on Israeli websites. Once I click on the article and the popup opens - the browser moves to a full screen mode. How do they achieve this?

You can reproduce this with:

1. Use Chrome on Mac OS X
2. Go to this page: http://www.haaretz.co.il/news/politi/.premium-1.2145182
3. Click on the article text once or twice until the popup opens.

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting fullscreen mode to my browser using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303151/getting-fullscreen-mode-to-my-browser-using-jquery) `:)` and see demo here **:==>** http://johndyer.name/lab/fullscreenapi/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to set a browser window to fullscreen using the HTML5 Fullscreen API. I'm not sure if the website you mentioned is using this approach though.

This is not a standard yet and thus will need vendor prefixes. You can check the level of browser support at [CANIUSE](http://caniuse.com/fullscreen) and HTML5 Rocks has a short tutorial [Fullscreen API.](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/10/Let-Your-Content-Do-the-Talking-Fullscreen-API)

Edit: Updated answer with code.

As I suspected, the website uses the HTML5 Fullscreen API. Refer to the code below on the page **which_popup.php**

```
function popup_(url, isOnClick) {

var is_popup_activated_domain = getCookieA('haaretz');
if (is_popup_activated_domain == "" && the_cookie == "") {
    if (isOnClick) {
        setCookieA('haaretz', 'yes', 14400);
        the_cookie = 'yes';
    }

    var chrome_full = false;
    if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
        chrome_full = true;
    }

    //....
    if (chrome_full) {
        document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
    }
}
}
```

It basically listens to a click event on the text, sets the browser to fullscreen and then opens the popup, so the popup also enters fullscreen. The api methods that you need are **webkitRequestFullscreen** to enable fullscreen mode and **webkitCancelFullScreen** to exit the fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 0):

This Links May Helpful For You..

http://johndyer.name/native-fullscreen-javascript-api-plus-jquery-plugin/

```
// mozilla proposal
element.requestFullScreen();
document.cancelFullScreen(); 

// Webkit (works in Safari and Chrome Canary)
element.webkitRequestFullScreen(); 
document.webkitCancelFullScreen(); 

// Firefox (works in nightly)
element.mozRequestFullScreen();
document.mozCancelFullScreen(); 

// W3C Proposal
element.requestFullscreen();
document.exitFullscreen();
```

try these also..

```
void webkitRequestFullScreen();
void webkitRequestFullScreenWithKeys();
void webkitCancelFullScreen();
```

Chrome implemented 'Kiosk Mode' in version 4.0.245.0. This is, essentially, a way to launch the browser in fullscreen mode with the Address Bar and Status Bar disabled. Some keyboard shortcuts (Fullscreen, for example) are also disabled.

On Windows: chrome.exe -kiosk http://yoursite.com/file.html

On everything else: chromium-browser --kiosk http://yoursite.com/file.html