# Full screen window either jquery or javascript for all browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone help me to make my window of browser at fullscreen with no bar, no navigation bar, no menu bar, no task bar at bottom and no cross or resizable button. lke when we press F11.

Comment: Take a look at the [Fullscreen API](http://davidwalsh.name/fullscreen)

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303151/getting-fullscreen-mode-to-my-browser-using-jquery

Comment: The fullscreen API is still experimental, but you can find a reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode)