# Call fullscreen script on pageload

Tags: javascript, vb.net, webforms, fullscreen, pageload

I'm developping a website in VB.Net by VS2013.
In webform View_SXCT.aspx (webform using masterpage), I have a javascript :

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function fullScreen() {
        var el = document.documentElement
            , rfs = // for newer Webkit and Firefox
                   el.requestFullScreen
                || el.webkitRequestFullScreen
                || el.mozRequestFullScreen
                || el.msRequestFullScreen
        ;
        if (typeof rfs != "undefined" && rfs) {
            rfs.call(el);
        } else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject != "undefined") {
            // for Internet Explorer
            var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
            if (wscript != null) {
                wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
            }
        }

    }
    // End -->
</script>
```

With a button. Everything is easy by `<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fullScreen();"><BUTTON></a>`
But How can I load that script on pageload. That's mean that webform will be fullscreen on pageload without any click on anything.
Thanks.

Comment: if you can use jQuery you can use the `$(document).ready()` function

Comment: I'm an amateur so can you explain? Thank

Comment: Have a look at these links, they may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303151/getting-fullscreen-mode-to-my-browser-using-jquery

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode

Comment: Thanks. I read that thread but that case is only fullscreen on user action (e.g a click), not on pageload (without any user action). That's my problem :(. It's so easy to fullscreen on click a button in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a few options for calling functions on page load.

If you are using jQuery the syntax is:

```
$(document).ready(fullScreen)
```

Without jQuery you can accomplish this with:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fullScreen);
```

But honestly the best way to call something on page load is to call the function with a script at the end of the HTML document. [For more info this is a good post on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup)

```
<html>
    <head>
    ...
    </head>
    <body>
    ...
    <scripts go here/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tryed to use fullscreen function but it just extract the window to maximum, not fullscreen like when you F11.