# I can't exit full screen

Tags: javascript, html, fullscreen

I used the Full Screen API to set the document body to fullscreen.

Now, all calls for `document.exitFullScreen` (with the appropriate prefixes) result in the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
at HTMLDivElement.fs.onclick
```

The function neither works in an event handler, or in the normal JS flow.

What is the problem, and how do I fix this? There is so little documentation, and I have not found anyone else with the error.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: It wasn't me, but I would guess it was because is lacking context in your problem, perhaps the code that calls the `exitFullScreen`. But my answer works on the assumption that the problem is related to where the code is being invoked.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error on calling `document.exitFullscreen()` directly, after showing a YouTube Video in an iframe in fullscreen.

For me this is working:

```
let exitFullscreen = document.exitFullscreen || document.mozCancelFullScreen || document.webkitExitFullscreen || document.msExitFullscreen;
if (exitFullscreen) {
    exitFullscreen.bind(document)();
}
```

It's necessary to `bind()` the function to `document`. Otherwise the context is probably the iframe, where invoking the function is illegal.

Comment: Thanks for the help ... `exitFullscreen.call(document)` works too

Answer (score 0):

Entering or exiting FullScreen is an invasive operation, and therefore, should only be triggered directly by an user action ([FullScreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API#When_a_fullscreen_request_fails)). Anything else will cause this error, for security reasons.

This question discussed how to invoke FullScreen without bumping in this Illegal action. You can code a solution to exit fullscreen based on their answer: [Getting fullscreen mode to my browser using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303151/getting-fullscreen-mode-to-my-browser-using-jquery)

The answer to that question has a solution without jQuery, which is cool.