# Display page in fullscreen using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display my page in fullscreen when it opens (WITHOUT user input). How can I do that?
I tried this code, but it doesnt't really work

```
function fullScreen(element) {
    if (element.requestFullscreen) {
        element.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (element.webkitrequestFullscreen) {
        element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (element.mozRequestFullscreen) {
        element.mozRequestFullscreen();
    }
}

var html = document.documentElement;
fullScreen(html);
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Does it do *nothing*, does it make the page almost fullscreen, does it make the page fullscreen for a second and then reverts back/reverts on scroll? Etc.

Comment: I think you may find proper examples here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_fullscreen_overlay.asp

Comment: @TylerH it does nothing, page opens as usual

Comment: @monogate thanks, but I need page to be full screen after it loads, without user interaction. Is that possible?

Comment: have you tryed this? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303151/getting-fullscreen-mode-to-my-browser-using-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303151/getting-fullscreen-mode-to-my-browser-using-jquery)

Comment: @LucaFontanot those examples require user input. I need to make page fullscreen on load

Comment: Fullscreen requests need to be called from within an event handler or otherwise they will be denied.   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today (6/2018) it's not possible to call fullscreen methods without  an event fired by user interaction. As doc said:

> Fullscreen requests need to be called from within an event handler or
>   otherwise they will be denied.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API We can't emulate that interaction. This example shows that behavior:

```
<div id="somediv">
    content
</div>

<script>

var div = document.getElementById("somediv");

function toggleFullScreen() {
    if (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitFullScreen) {
      if (div.mozRequestFullScreen) {   
        div.mozRequestFullScreen();
      } else {
        div.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
      }
    } else {
      if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
      } else {
        document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
      }
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      console.log("click");
      toggleFullScreen();
  }, false);


div.click();

</script>
```

This example shows that console.log("click"); was executed without interaction but fullScreen is denied. If user perform a click (user event), fullScreen is allowed.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Than another question. How can I launch default system browser in kiosk mode with specified url? That is actually what I needed

Comment: It's something like: google-chrome --kiosk http://example.com in linux and windows: chrome.exe --kiosk http://example.com, I'm not sure Firefox

Comment: Oh, also, is there any way to emulate that user input?
Probably that would be too easy

Comment: We can't do that for fullscreen. In the code, .click() emulates a click and doesn't work, that is the problem. No matter if we emulate a click or a mouseenter or whatever, fullscreen needs an event triggered by user. It needs a real interaction.