# JQuery dialog fullscreen

Tags: jquery, dialog, fullscreen

Is it possible to make JQuery ui dialog fit to fullscreen by that I mean complete fullscreen outside browser boundaries?

If it is how can it be done?

I was thinking about resizing the document body to fullscreen and the dialog window.

Comment: I was thinking if I keep a monitor next to another it should expand to  that monitor too ;)

Comment: Outside the browser window, hic est OS. Don't go there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible, since the jQuery UI dialog it's basically HTML elements styled to look like a window. What you asking for would require to render HTML outside the browser instance it's rendering the page and that's not possible.

The far you can get is to resize the browser window, and make the jQuery dialog fit the whole page. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen), you can find how to resize the browser. There's even a possible solution to force some browsers to go full screen.