# IE11 full screen on element

Tags: fullscreen, internet-explorer-11

IE 11 has been out just one day as of this posting.
I cannot get an element to go full screen (div or document)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn265028

msRequestFullscreen will error 'object does not support this...)

However, the above msdn example will work on passing a target - makeFullScreen(evt.target).
Can I get an div to go fullscreen as in following jquery code?:

```
var xxx = $('#container');
xxx.msRequestFullscreen();
```

Or better still: click a button then have a div or the entire document to go fullscreen?
As it stands now, when a click a button, it's the button that goes full screen.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is actually a small misconception of JQuery. JQuery-ing an ID doesn't actually return the element found - it returns a "JQuery object" which allows many actions on that element (or, on a series of elements if you used a class selector)

I don't have IE11 available so I can't test for you, but try this. The [0] should retrieve the element itself.

```
var xxx = $('#container')[0]; xxx.msRequestFullscreen();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
var xxx = $('#container');
xxx.msRequestFullscreen();
```

This is wrong, because you're trying to call a DOM method on a jQuery object.

jQuery calls like `$('#container')` return jQuery objects. You can do lots of things with these objects, but one thing you can't do is call standard DOM methods. For that, you need an actual DOM object.

jQuery objects contain an array of matching DOM objects, which you can access via `[0]` for the first one, and `[1]`, etc if there was more than one matching element. So you can do your call by changing your second line as follows:

```
xxx[0].msRequestFullscreen();
```

This will call the `msRequestFullscreen()` on the DOM element rather than the jQuery element, and that should work for you.

In this case, you don't even need jQuery at all, since you're not using any of the jQuery functionality. You could simply use `document.getElementById('container')` to get the DOM object in the first place rather than the jQuery method. Then you don't need the `[0]` syntax on the second line because you've already got the DOM object.

Finally, you might want to be careful of course, because this is an IE-specific method; the `ms` at the front of the name tells you that, which means that your code won't work in other browsers, even if they support the same feature. You need to do it in a cross-browser way. There are some tips on how to do this here: [How to make the window full screen with Javascript (stretching all over the screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen)