# Jquery: click to trigger a keydown event

Tags: jquery, fullscreen, onkeydown, eventtrigger

How can I trigger a keydown event when a button is clicked?

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
    e.which = 122; // # Some key code value

    $('.button-fullscreen').click(function(){
        $(window).trigger(e);
        return false;
    });
```

I want to trigger the key **F11** on the keyboard when the button is clicked. Is it possible?

Comment: use full screen API to full screen https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode

Comment: i have tried that. it does not work with my layout as my website layout has a horizontal scrollbar at the bottom page.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this and adapt it to 122:

[Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events)

Otherwise, if you are trying to fullscreen - why both with F11?:

[How to make the window full screen with Javascript (stretching all over the screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen)

Comment: i have tried that one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen but it does not work with my layout. thanks.