# Fullscreen mode for a video player

Tags: javascript

I was trying to make full screen for my video player. I am using JWplayer.. what i want is a full screen like [this](http://www.youtube.com/embed/bz51cYFBHYo)

```
var player_width = $(window).width();
var player_height = $(window).height();
```

Code above wont work for this, i was wondering on how this will work. I was looking for some solution for this but i cant find one. I am getting this kind of result..

[image]

Comment: Isn't this information available in the JW documentation?

Comment: i was using a free edition of jw player..

Comment: yes your code has to work , any link ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make in Javascript full screen windows (stretching all over the screen)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen)

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**

The fullscreen feature you are trying to omit of youtube is coded in ActionScript in their player. JW Player **does not offer this feature**. However you can set full screen without measuring the `window'`s height and width like this:

```
jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
'flashplayer': '/jwplayer/player.swf',
'width': '100%',
'height': '100%',
});
```

*One trick* is too trigger browser default player by linking the direct video link on a link somewhere or on the double click of the player (can be easily done using jQuery)

Another trick is too trigger the full screen of browser as shown [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7525760/295264)

**Earlier Answer:**

If you attempting to resize the player based on the screen's dimension, make sure you are getting the values after the document is loaded and that plugin is initiated after wards.

```
$(function() {
   var player_width = $(window).width();
   var player_height = $(window).height(); 

   //After this initiate the plugin

});
```

*Except this, there is nothing wrong with your code.*

Answer (score -1):

```
function makeBig() {
           var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
           myVideo.height = myVideo.videoHeight * 2;
       }
       function makeNormal() {
           var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
           myVideo.height = myVideo.videoHeight;
       }
```

Comment: thats making it 2x hight. not full screen

Answer (score -1):

You can change the jwplayer height and width  try this

```
           var windowWidth = $(window).width(); //retrieve current window width
           var windowHeight = $(window).height(); //retrieve current window height
          jwplayer("video_id").resize(windowWidth , windowHeight );
```