# Maximize browser window automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, window, maximize

I'm developing a web application in PHP. I need to maximize the browser window automatically when my web page is opened in the browser. Is it possible? Is there any code for this? Will it support all kind of browsers? Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Comment: With no browser plugin and no popups... i think its not possible.

Comment: Only window.open can maximize the browser,but I think you don't need it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make in Javascript full screen windows (stretching all over the screen)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen)

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to maximize current window, but you could use the full screen mode of html5, supported from html5 capable browsers:
[Using fullscreen mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode)