# How To make FullScreen window of test panel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring

I have one problem in making full screen window during test in online examination project. I have used javascript function from which F11 key pressed. But this function only used on onclick event. I want to call this function on window load.

Please suggest me and if you have another solution for this problem or for full screen window then give your ideas.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen

Comment: only single method present here