# What's wrong with my script that it doesn't allow auto-fullscreen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, fullscreen, onload

I want my page to be shown in full screen mode when loaded. I read this article [How to make in Javascript full screen windows (stretching all over the screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen)

And I am using the suggested solutions/codes for it. But it seems not working. I have the latest version of Chrome and I am sure it supports `full screen` mode. But it is still not working.

```
var elem = document.body; // Make the body go full screen.
requestFullScreen(elem);

function requestFullScreen(element) {
// Supports most browsers and their versions.
var requestMethod = element.requestFullScreen || element.webkitRequestFullScreen || element.mozRequestFullScreen || element.msRequestFullScreen;

if (requestMethod) { // Native full screen.
    requestMethod.call(element);
} else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject !== "undefined") { // Older IE.
    var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    if (wscript !== null) {
            wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried running this code under the `load()` event of `jQuery`.

```
$(document).load(function(){
    var elem = document.body;
    requestFullScreen(elem);
});
```

but both is not working. Could anyone please tell me what's the cause of this problem? Thank you.

Comment: I think it needs interaction from the user. You can not automate fullscreen.

Comment: Just a side note: Why are you using `$(window).load(function(){` inside `$(document).ready(function(){`?

Comment: you can not send the page to fullscreen automatically, needs to be triggered by the user.

Comment: @Satpal my bad.. sorry, I edited it.

Comment: @AminJafari are there any tricks or option to automate the fullscreen?

Comment: It would be a pretty pointless restriction in the spec if it could be bypassed.

Comment: unfortunately no, the browser doesn't let it as a security point! you can check out my website and see how I did it! you have to let the user to choose! http://www.a-jafari.com