# how do I make my slide show full screen on my webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So im trying to stretch my slideshow to be fullscreen like the one on www.dealix.com (something you can refer to) Im currently using Jquery is it a css code that has to be implemented or do the images have to be sized to fit the screen and if so what is the default width of an internet browser thanks so much! please be easy on me as im only in my second month of coding!

```
CSS:


<!--
#fadein {
    position:relative;
    height:320px;
    width:320px;
}

#fadein img {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
-->
```

Html/Javascript:

```
</div>
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();

setInterval(function () {
    $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
                             .next('img')
                             .fadeIn()
                             .end()
                             .appendTo('.fadein');
}, 4000); // 4 seconds
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What about if you put the `height` and `width` properties with `100%` value?

EDIT:

Put also this on the css:

```
    body{
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }
```

Comment: what put 100% in the css or in the img=src?

Comment: In the CSS, `fadeIn` id, `width: 100%` and `height: 100%`

Comment: Okay i did that but theres still a little white showing probably about 10px wide how do i get it to cover that?

Comment: put `padding: 0` and/or `margin:0` also

Comment: pushed beyone the page because everything i have made is in the middle of the image so i only want that put showing on the webpage

Comment: It would be easier if you put the code online so we can test it

Comment: were do i go to do that jsfiddle? im new to all this

Comment: jsfiddle.net, put the code, save and then share the link, I guess

Answer (score 0):

IF you are looking for full screen within browser use width:100%; height:100%;

or if you are looking total full screen refer to this question

[How to make the window full screen with Javascript (stretching all over the screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen)