# Full screen website

Tags: javascript, css

I have a presentation on my website and I am looking for a script which will make it fullscreen.
But not fullscreen just as a page. I need completaly full screen without browser bar etc. 
It must work exactly the same like you click the movie full screen. 
I can not find it. Should i use CSS for that ?

Comment: Instead of the linked duplicate [this answer to "How to make in Javascript full screen windows (stretching all over the screen)"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28589187/205233) looks more promising.

Comment: Mozilla has a handy tutorial on this over at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode