# Script that will maximise the viewing space of my google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a dashboard contained within a google sheet which I share with other users. Upon opening the google sheet, I instruct them to do the following:

Click *'View > Full screen*, press F11 on keyboard

This maximises the view and enhances the experience of the user.

My question is whether there is a script available which I could trigger when the user opens the sheet that could achieve the above?

I have searched for answers and found plenty of relevant material but nothing which I was able to apply and get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Apps Script method for changing the VIEW to FULL SCREEN.  f11 is specific to the browser.  You can write client side JavaScript in a Dialog or Sidebar.   You could look at this post:

[StackOverflow - How to make in Javascript full screen windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen)

Comment: The linked answer is a bit outdated. There is now full screen mode but still not possible to do it in a sheet. Would need to be a html app