# How youtube iframe embed allows us to view full screen, while iframe content cannot displayed outside fixed width and height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

As per iframe documentation, whatever link we are given, the content will be visible only inside the iframe boundaries. How youtube iframe embed allows us to view full screen, while iframe content cannot displayed outside fixed width and height? is there any way to achieve through javascript?

Comment: Javacript fullscreen should work from iframe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. If I insert video using 
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eeoKyTHn5Kg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
Then it loads the player of width 560px and height 315px. I have no idea how on clicking maximize button on player, it expands to full screen out of the iframe window. how is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Either showing a video using html5 or using flash
It's "your device" that allows youtube to display it in full screen because it recognices the video
Not with javascript, sorry

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but now with windows universal apps you can embed a web site on a windows frame gaining access to extra functionallity from the windows apis