# How to show 2 videos in single HTML5 Full-screen mode

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, fullscreen, html5-fullscreen

I have 2 video tags. How can I show a single full-screen mode containing both videos (for example, a video chat, where I want to see my own camera, and my friend's at the same time)?

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer

I don't think there is a way to use the fullscreen mode like you want to do right now.

#### Solution

You can make an element go fullscreen such as **a container that wraps the two videos**. Supported in Chrome 15, Firefox 10, Safari 5.1, IE 10.

[MDN reference to the fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API)

#### Other solution

You could fill the browser you your two video with something like

```
#video1, #video2 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    float:left;
}
```

and somewhere have a little message saying *"Put your browser in fullscreen for better experience"* or have a button that toggle an almost fullscreen mode like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = maxWindow;

    function maxWindow() {
        window.moveTo(0, 0);


        if (document.all) {
            top.window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
        }

        else if (document.layers || document.getElementById) {
            if (top.window.outerHeight < screen.availHeight || top.window.outerWidth < screen.availWidth) {
                top.window.outerHeight = screen.availHeight;
                top.window.outerWidth = screen.availWidth;
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Code taken from that [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen)