# How to make an iFrame to go fullscreen on a button click?

Tags: javascript, iframe, onclick, fullscreen

I would to make the iFrame to appear on fullscreen with a button click using JavaScript.

```
<iframe id="iframe_view" class="embed-responsive-item container well well-small span6" style="height: 720px; width: 1280px; background-color: #2e2e2e;" src="https://www.google.com/" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You will have to do two things: make the window fullscreen, and then the `<iframe>` to fill up the whole size.

You can make it go fullscreen with JS such as in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7525760/2397327).

Then, to make it full size, just add a few styles, like below. What this JS script does is add a class with those styles to the `<iframe>`.

**JS**

```
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].className = "fullScreen";
```

**CSS**

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.fullScreen {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

See [this partially working* example](http://jsfiddle.net/jlam55555/o5njka95/6/) on JSFiddle.

<sub>*partially working because JSFiddle doesn't allow the fullscreen method because it deems it unsafe. But it should work for you.</sub>

Comment: thanks for the example and the answer. It was helpful!

Comment: this is a copy of: https://cmsdk.com/css3/how-do-you-code-a-button-that-can-make-an-iframe-go-full-screen-when-clicked.html

Comment: @Theodore You have it backwards. This post is two years older.