# Full screen on the button in the frame

Tags: javascript, html, fullscreen

How to call fullscreen mode in frame on my site? Thank you...

[image]

```html
<iframe width='640' height='360' src='https://roundme.com/embed/11663/28535' frameborder='0' webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768509/how-to-make-an-iframe-to-go-fullscreen-on-a-button-click

Answer (score 0):

You need to request user permission to full screen i believe. [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) MDN post goes into more detail. If you check caniuse.com you'll see that theres a lot of partial support, be sure to check the caveats.

According to MDN you need to call `requestFullScreen` on the element.

Some HTML:

```
<video controls id="myvideo">
  <source src="somevideo.webm"></source>
  <source src="somevideo.mp4"></source>
</video>
```

Some JS for it:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myvideo");
if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
  elem.requestFullscreen();
}
```

Be sure to go through the docs though, as it mentions some interesting CSS caveats between Gecko and Webkit browsers.

Comment: caveat: fullscreen api does not work in iOS and android as of january 3rd 2019

Answer (score -1):

The :fullscreen CSS pseudo-class selector is used to select and style an element that is being displayed in full-screen mode.

https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/fullscreen/

Comment: While this is true, that isn't what the question is asking.