# Enter full screen whenever page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, fullscreen

I'm working on asp.net quiz application. The mandatory requirement of this application is: when the application starts (page is requested), it automatically enters into full screen.

Now I tried dozen of solutions (JS & Jquery's plugins)

1. [JS Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen)
2. [Mozila's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API)
3. [Jquery Plugins](https://plugins.jquery.com/fullscreen/)

a number of different jquery's plugins, but Chrome & Firefox are not allowing me to do so. Because it states that it needs user interaction for that.

Can somebody please help me out of this situation? Solution can be browser dependent.

Details about application:

1. Total 5 aspx pages.
2. One page is an iframe/frame in another page.

Comment: is a "splashscreen" requiring user interaction (a click) an option?

Comment: sorry I don;t understand. Can you please explain a little more ?

Comment: well on page load show a [splash screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splash_screen) with something inviting the user to click on the page (something like "Start this awesome app !"). This way you have the "user  interaction" required by the Fullscreen API

Comment: Yep tried it. but whenever I redirect user to another page, it exit from full screen.

Comment: yes, you'll have to make your app single paged (using iframe or ajax+DOM manipulation)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The thing is I developed everything else :/
Is there any way around ? Like another language ? Action script ? coffe script ? anything in your mind ?

Comment: JavaScript is the only language that will be cross-browser compatible.

Comment: solution can be browser dependent. I mean if solution works onnly on FF or only on chrome. I can afford that.

Comment: Quick and dirty solution. Let's create another page which will be our container page. Put an Iframe there, calculate Iframe height width attribute based on the screen size. make the first page as iframe source. on the iframe put frameborder=0, so from user perspective it will look like single page.

Comment: can you please post this in answer @SatyakiChatterjee

Comment: @SikanderHayyat -  Posted is answer section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty solution. Let's create another page which will be our container page. Put an Iframe there, calculate Iframe height width attribute based on the screen size. make the first page as iframe source. on the iframe put frameborder=0, so from user perspective it will look like single page

For full screen check this link http://www.css-jquery-design.com/2013/11/javascript-jquery-fullscreen-browser-window-html5-technology/

Comment: Let me try this solution :)

Comment: It seems that we have no solution but this. I create a simple aspx page and made an iframe and redirects it within iframe. But a problem remains there, which is when I refreshed the page (crl+r) then it displays the first page which has been set in src of iframe.

Comment: Thanks for your solution @satyaki. I really appreciate your help :D

Comment: @SikanderHayyat -  Thanks.. Can you please mark this as answer?

Comment: Marked :D Thanks once again :)