# Firefox how to go fullscreen without user input

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make a page go fullscreen on loading. I tried below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
webkitEnterFullscreen();

</script>

</head>
<body onload="mozRequestFullScreen();">
<p> Hello </p>
</body>
</html>
```

But it does not seem to work. I have seen examples where user button is provided to go fullscreen, but none where whole page needs to e displayed in fullscreen mode.

I'm using firefox to test.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. You are calling a function, but it is not defined anywhere in your script tags. Are you missing a script reference?

Comment: Have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen

Comment: The simplest way is to add a [splash-screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splash_screen) with some button the user needs to click on to go to the app => You've got your user-interaction.

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/ru/questions/1029031

Comment: This is not duplicate of "How to make the window full screen".

Answer (score 1):

> I need to make a page go fullscreen on loading.

**You can’t.**

The full screen APIs function only in the context of a user-initiated action, such as the event handler for a click.