# Can I open the iframe in FullScreen if screen size is small?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have this link.

> http://minjago.com/beta/index.php/front/game/499

I want that if my screen size is less than 500, the `allowfullscreen` is triggered to true. How can I achieve this? I don't want it to be done via CSS.

Comment: You can't force full screen without a user event

Comment: Agree with ^^^^^^ [How to make in Javascript full screen windows (stretching all over the screen)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen) might help you

Comment: Can i make a custom event and trigger it somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of relying on CSS media queries, you can use [`matchMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Testing_media_queries) to manage how your app handles viewport sizes. The Full Screen API requires user interaction, so this procedure requires a little bit of CSS.

1. The details are commented in the Snippet.
2. Because of the sandbox restrictions, the Snippet will not function correctly. So a [<kbd>**PLUNKER**</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/ygro800Ae7rtVIRI6MNd?p=preview) is also available for review as well.
3. When reviewing the Plunker, click the blue button that opens the preview in a new window.
4. Resize the new window width to 500px or less.
5. The viewport should darken which is a cue to the user that there's an overlay.
6. Once the overlay is clicked, it will go full screen.

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>fs</title>
  <style>
    /* Although CSS is excluded by request from OP, this is 
    | an exception and in this circumstance necessary. User
    | must interact for Full Screen API to work. In abscence
    | of a pure programmitic solution, one must rely on CSS
    | and/or HTML.
    */
    .overlay {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 1;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
      display: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <!--Add this div to HTML-->
  <div class='overlay'></div>
  <iframe id="fullscreen" src="http://www.example.com" width='100%' height='500' allowfullscreen></iframe>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    /*
        | Create a mediaQueryList (mql) with a query that matches
        | a viewport of 500px or less.
        | Pass it into the function mqr()
        | Add a listener to mql and assign mqr() as event handler.
        | Reference target as a jQuery object (iframe).
        */
    var $obj = $('iframe');
    var mql = window.matchMedia("screen and (max-device-width: 500px)");
    mqr(mql);
    mql.addListener(mqr);

    /*
    | Reference .overlay as jQuery object 
    | (overlay is display: none initially)
    | Reference #fullscreen as a plain object.
    | Use the .matches property to compare mql to viewport
    | If the viewport is < 500px then...
    | ...show() overlay then...
    | ...pass overlay and fs to the fs() function
    */
    function mqr(mql) {
        var overlay = $('.overlay');

        if (mql.matches) {
          overlay.show();
          fs(overlay, $obj);
        }
      }
      // isFullScreen() function will verify if full screen is active
    var isFullScreen = function() {
      return !!(document.fullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.msFullscreenElement || document.fullscreenElement);
    }

    /*
    | fs() function will delegate click event on a given
    | element (first parameter).
    | When triggered, it will target the element (second 
    | parameter) and dereference it in order to use the 
    | Full Screen API.
    | The isFullScreen function determines if full 
    | screen is already active...
    | if not active requestFullscreen method is called...
    | ...if it is, then exitFullscreen method is called.
    */
    function fs(overlay, $obj) {
      overlay.on('click', function() {
        var fs = $obj[0];
        if (!isFullScreen()) {
          if (fs.requestFullscreen) {
            fs.requestFullscreen();
          } else if (fs.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            fs.mozRequestFullScreen();
          } else if (fs.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
            fs.webkitRequestFullscreen();
          } else if (fs.msRequestFullscreen) {
            fs.msRequestFullscreen();
          }
        } else {
          if (document.exitFullscreen) {
            document.exitFullscreen();
          } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
          } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
            document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
          } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
            document.msExitFullscreen();
          }
        }
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you can't find another way, here's how to do it with CSS. Create two iframes, one having `allowfullscreen` set as true and another set to false. With CSS have the iframe that has `allowfullscreen` set to true hidden on screens larger then 500 while having the one set as false hidden on screens sized 500 or smaller.

CSS:

```css
@media (max-width:500px){.hidden-large{display:none!important}}
@media (min-width:501px){.hidden-small{display:none!important}}
```

Then include the class `hidden-large` or `hidden-small` in the iframes.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use a modal blocker...it involved another step in the UX but gets the job done.

HTML:

```
<iframe id="fullscreen" src="http://jsfiddle.net" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<div id="confirm" style="display:none;position:fixed;width:100%;height:100%;text-align:center;padding-top:30px;background:rgba(0,0,0,.75);top:0;left:0;">
  <button id="allow">Allow fullscreen</button>
  <button id="cancel">Cancel fullscreen</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
  if( jQuery( window ).width() <= 600 )
  {
    jQuery('#confirm').show();
    jQuery('#allow').on('click', function(e){
      document.getElementById('fullscreen').webkitRequestFullScreen();
      jQuery('#confirm').hide();
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
    jQuery('#confirm,#cancel').on('click', function(){
      jQuery('#confirm').hide();
    });
  }
});
```

You'll have to add checks to determine which RequestFullscreen() to use (moz/webkit etc). Otherwise, this example works, can test here: https://jsfiddle.net/tsdexter/g1evfepj/

HINT: make the viewport in jsfiddle less than 600px wide to see it working.