# Electron, trigger fullscreen programmatically

Tags: javascript, electron

Is there a way to trigger the `F11` built-in fullscreen feature programmatically within Electron?

```
$('.fs-btn').on("click", function(){
   // Function call here
});
```

Inside something like that. The window is not starting out fullscreen, but I'd like the option to be present - and not only from the menu/shortcuts :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think I thought about this the wrong way. 
I found a solution using things outside of Electron. It might not even be Electron's place to expose functions like that :)

[How to make the window full screen with Javascript (stretching all over the screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-the-window-full-screen-with-javascript-stretching-all-over-the-scre)