# What other vanilla JS functions are there that are similar to alert, confirm and prompt?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, fullscreen

I'm trying to reproduce a particular bug on a particular device (it's a tablet).

The bug is reproduced when I use `alert()`, `prompt()` and `confirm()`.

I'm looking for a similar functions. Looking at the three functions above, their similarities seem to be

- They pause execution,
- They occupy the entire screen (by opening a modal), and
- They're built-ins and don't require extra libraries, etc., to run.

A Google search didn't show up any results besides these three.

I did find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-the-window-full-screen-with-javascript-stretching-all-over-the-scre), which could be useful (haven't tried it out yet).

Comment: I tried the link out, and it did not reproduce the bug.

Comment: please add the code which produces the bug.