# Jquery button Clicked allow F11 fullscreen mode

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, fullscreen

I'm trying to achieve something simple but I'm new to jquery and seems too difficult to me.
I want that, when i press on a button, my browser will go in fullscreen mode like when you press F11
I searched in Stackoverflow for solutions but none of them worked.

```js
var viewer = $("#a")[0];
var rFS = viewer.mozRequestFullScreen || viewer.webkitRequestFullscreen || viewer.requestFullscreen;
rFS.call(viewer);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="a">Open Fullscreen</button>
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-the-window-full-screen-with-javascript-stretching-all-over-the-scre

Answer (score 0):

```
var viewer = $("#a .classname .childelement")[0];
var rFS = viewer.mozRequestFullScreen || viewer.webkitRequestFullscreen || viewer.requestFullscreen;
    rFS.call(viewer);
```