# How does netflix fullscreen feature work?

Tags: javascript

I know that Netflix has moved from Silverlight to React. After looking through the source code and not finding what I'm looking for, I want to understand how Netflix can enter the user into fullscreen mode when clicking on the fullscreen button. The DOM window can't be resized through JS...unless I'm missing something. So what kind of technology is Netflix using to completely take over the screen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make the window full screen with Javascript (stretching all over the screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-the-window-full-screen-with-javascript-stretching-all-over-the-scre)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a web api to control [full screen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API):

Enter Full screen:

> document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();

Exit Full screen:

> document.exitFullscreen();